# Ubuntu 21.04 Desktop Clicking Issue

Tags: gnome, 21.04

I have just done a fresh install of Ubuntu 21.04 today, and as soon as the installation finished I noticed an issue in which clicking and holding on the desktop produced a selection area away from where the mouse is located (seen in the attached video). Is there any possible fix for this?

https://youtu.be/HqqzgEwbDf8